# Is this safe against SQL injection?

Tags: oracle, sql-injection

Is the below form safe against SQL injection?  I have to do this because the `p_select_statement` would be a simple `select * from table where lastModifiedTime > :p_asof and <conditions>`, but the code that calls `getByFilter` expects the columns to be in the order `col1, col2, col3` while `select *` may return `col2, col3, col1`

```
OPEN CURSOR <dynamic_select_statement> USING <bind variable>
```

Example...

```
PROCEDURE getByFilter (
    p_select_statement IN VARCHAR2,
    p_asof IN TIMESTAMP,
    p_cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS
    full_select_statement VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
    full_select_statement := 'SELECT
        col1,
        col2,
        col3
    FROM (' || p_select_statement || ')';
    OPEN p_cur FOR full_select_statement USING p_asof;
END getByFilter;
```

Comment: Consider one set `p_select_statement := '{...whatever you consider as valid...} union all select username as col1, PASSWORD as col2, null as col3 from DBA_USERS'`

Comment: Thanks.  That is very useful.  So it can leak data.  Can it delete or update some other table?  `p_select_statement` isn't dynamically constructed.  It is read from a configuration file.  From the answers, I think this approach is better than `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`

Comment: No within a select you cannot execute any DML

Comment: @zrb It couldn't directly delete or update, but it could call a PL/SQL function that deletes or updates something.  The PL/SQL function would have to be defined with `pragma autonomous_transaction;`.  It's not common but it is something you may need to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

No, not if the conditions can be set dynamically:

```
VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR;

DECLARE
  conditions VARCHAR2(4000)
    := '1 = 0 UNION ALL '
     || 'select username AS col1, password AS col2, other_column AS col3 '
     || 'FROM your_secret_password_table';
  sql        VARCHAR2(4000)
    := 'select * from table where lastModifiedTime > :p_asof and ' || conditions;
BEGIN
  PROCEDURE getByFilter (
    p_select_statement => sql,
    p_asof             => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    p_cur              => :curr
  );
END;
/

PRINT cur;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your example is clearly an example of SQL injection. It counts as SQL injection if your procedure executes some input verbatim as a query (or part of a query, as in this case).

To answer your question about whether unsafe input could do damage, I can think of two possibilities:

- The SELECT passed as an argument to the procedure could be designed to be very resource-intensive. For example a query with a large cartesian join:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM AnyTable
  CROSS JOIN AnyTable
  CROSS JOIN AnyTable
  CROSS JOIN AnyTable
  CROSS JOIN AnyTable
  ORDER BY 1;
  ```

  Generates a result set of a few trillion rows, and attempts to sort it. That could be a denial-of-service attack.
- The SELECT includes calling a stored function that modifies data.

  ```
  SELECT SomeFunctionThatDeletes() FROM AnyTable;
  ```

Whether your procedure is unsafe depends on whether the calling code allows untrusted input to become the argument to your procedure.

Suppose you had some safeguard like this (written in PHP, but the same applies to any language):

```
$user_option = $_GET['option'];
$queries = [
  1 => 'select * from table where lastModifiedTime > :p_asof and <conditions>',
  2 => 'select * from table where lastModifiedTime < :p_asof and <conditions>'
];

$stmt = $db->prepare('call getByFilter(?)');
$stmt->execute([$queries[$user_option]);
```

Now the user can pick with an input of '1' or '2' *which* query to run, but they have to pick one or the other of these hard-coded queries. They can't do anything mischievous like change the SQL query that is run.

That's a type of **whitelisting**. In other words, your application code must limit the choices so that the user's input can pick only safe choices. The user input should never be allowed to be executed as SQL directly without some kind of whitelisting like this.

You could also implement the whitelisting inside your procedure.